# How to extend/inherit/join from two seperate Dockerfiles, multi-stage builds?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a deployment process which I currently achieve via `docker-machine` and `docker-compose`. (I have multiple services deployed which are interelated - one a Django application, and another the `resty-auto-ssl` Docker image (ref: https://github.com/Valian/docker-nginx-auto-ssl)

My `docker-compose` file is something like:

```
services:
  web:

  nginx:

  postgres:
```

(N.B. I'm not using postgres in production, that's merely as example).

What I need to do, is to essentially bundle all of this up into one built Docker image.

Each service references a different `Dockerfile` base, one for the Django application:

```
FROM python:3.7.2-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron && apt-get -y install nano

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/init.sh"]
```

And one for the valian/docker-nginx-auto-ssl image:

```
FROM valian/docker-nginx-auto-ssl

COPY nginx.conf /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/
```

I assume theoretically I could some how join these two Dockerfiles into one? Would this be a case of utilising multi-stage Docker builds (https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#before-multi-stage-builds) to be used into a joined docker-compose service?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can join images, a Dockerfile image is like a VM hard disk, it would be like saying I want to join 2 hard disk images together.  These images may even be different versions of Linux and now even Windows.   If you want 1 single image,  you could build one yourself by starting off with a base mage like Alpine Linux and then install all the dependencies you want.

But the good news the images you use from Dockfile you can get the source for these, so all the hard work of what to put in your Docker is done for you.

eg.  For the python bit -> https://github.com/jfloff/alpine-python

And then for nginx-auto -> https://github.com/Valian/docker-nginx-auto-ssl

Because the nginx-auto-sll is based on alphie-fat, I would suggest using that one.  And then get the details from both Docker files and append them to each other.

Once you have created this image you can then use again & again. So although it might be a pain setting up initially, it pays dividends later.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, thanks Keith. My next question would be - what even does Alpine fat mean? Does it just come with "more" than the slim?

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos  I believe so yes, you can find what exactly inside each here -> https://hub.docker.com/r/openresty/openresty/  I've a feeling looking at the fat one it's maybe the openssl stuff that ngnix will want / require.